# download the files in resources of xcode project

Tags: iphone

I have a project which includes aprox 100 images and 101 files. which creates the application size 85MB on itunes. users can't download that much huge application.

**Is there any way to download the sound files in resources of xcode project instead of adding all the files in project and then upload it to itunes?**

Thanks guys.
Best Regards,
Naveed Butt

Answer (score 0):

Users can download apps of any size via iTunes. I believe the largest one so far is close to 2GB. The only limitation is that AT&T only allows a 20MB application to be downloaded over 3G or the older EDGE network.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your audio files in a server of your choice. And when needed download the file from the server, if needed , you can save the files in the document directory of your application.

So when loading an audio file, 
   - check it its already in the document directory,
   - if not, download and save in the document directory and then load